# How does google maps keep track of your location history?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Im building an app that tracks your location.

Im currently using a foreground service that logs the location on a database, this means that while my service is running a notification is showing to let the user know that their location is being logged, even when the app is closed.
Ive checked many apps that do something similar and they all work like that, except for google maps, on the "history" page it tells you the route you took even if you didnt have the app open nor it shows a notification letting you know that the location is being tracked.

Does anyone know how google achieve that?

Comment: Background Location Permission: Google Maps requests the "background location" permission, which is a special permission introduced in Android 10 (API level 29) and later. This permission allows the app to access location even when it's running in the background. Users are prompted to grant this permission when installing or updating the app.

Comment: A certified android device has google play services which has system permissions granted by the device vendor to record location without a foreground service. Google only does that if you enable the location history. So google maps doesn't do any tracking, it simply ask google's servers for your history. You can see the same result on google maps on the web when logged in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.